# Set-ACL deletes bultin accounts

Tags: powershell, permissions, share, ntfs

I'm trying to **add** permissions to an existing share. The share has the 4 default permissions on a Windows Server 2012 (creator owner, System...).

When I run the script from my Win7 client it deletes all ntfs-permissions and add only the account from the script. Any ideas???

```
$folder = Get-Acl "\\win-gv2fnajsqvu\a-og"
$newACL = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("test\user2","FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$folder.AddAccessRule($newACL)
Set-Acl "\\win-gv2fnajsqvu\a-og" -aclobject $Folder
```

Comment: FWIW, I was not able to reproduce the issue. It worked as expected when I tried it.

Comment: Are these inherited properties that are being removed? If so, try forcing `SetAccessRuleProtection` to `$true` for "preserveInheritance" on the `$newACL` object and see if that helps.

Comment: By default existing ACEs are preserved. You'd need to run `$folder.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $true)` to disable inheritance and remove inherited permissions.

Comment: `$folder.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $false)` removes inheritance, not `($true, $true)`. Also, I meant `$folder` above - not `$newACL` - whoops.

Comment: Thanks. It works! I´ve an additional tip: When you modify the permissions with the administravie path, it work´s too. I.e. "\\servername\c$\a-og". With this path, all other permissions are not modified.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Are you sure? According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection(v=vs.110).aspx), `($true, $true)` would preserve inherited access rules while protecting from further change through inheritance, while `($true, $false)` removes inherited access rules after protection.

Comment: @Kohlbrr You're right. Apparently I misremembered. Sorry about the noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like these are inherited properties that are being removed. Try forcing `SetAccessRuleProtection` to `$true` for "preserveInheritance" on the `$folder` object:

```
$folder = Get-Acl "\\win-gv2fnajsqvu\a-og"
$folder.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $true)
$newACL = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("test\user2","FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$folder.AddAccessRule($newACL)
Set-Acl "\\win-gv2fnajsqvu\a-og" -aclobject $folder
```